# a file use usepackage mathtimy

Tags: packages, missing

A file used package like that :

```
\usepackage{times,amsmath,mathtimy}
```

making pdf show error:

> "mathtimy.sty"

How can i fix this problem?

I have search the `"mathtimy.sty"` but not found on internet.

Pleas help us

Thnaks in advance

Comment: [Internet search](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=-xzcW5n1G6nJrgSIyaroBQ&q=mathtimy.sty&oq=mathtimy.sty&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i19k1j0i13i30i19k1l2j0i13i5i30i19k1.593.593.0.984.1.1.0.0.0.0.94.94.1.1.0....0...1.2.64.psy-ab..0.1.91....0.SKUX72nar4Q)

Comment: Maybe it's `mathtime.sty`; but the fonts it would use are not free.

Answer (score 1):

Quite likely, you mistyped the package name, which should be `mathtime`.

The [package can be found on CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/psnfssx/mathtime), but using it requires a set of commercial fonts.

You're best served if, instead, you do

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

This will provide Times based fonts and a much richer supply of symbols than `mathtime`.

Answer (score 0):

Mathtimy is a style file calling Mathtime, which was used in Y&YTex, which is no longer supported. My copy of the file was downloaded in 1998.